# Do not send raw body to AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda function written in node. I have a HTTP API in API Gateway which calls this lambda function.

The "issue" that I'm having is that my request payload which is a JSON, is sent wrapped in a raw body along with a bunch of other fields which I don't really need in my lambda.

How can I have the HTTP API to only send my payload?

If I use a REST API, at least by default, it works the way I expect.

Comment: It maybe not supported in HTTP api. HTTP supports only a [fraction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) of features from REST API.

Comment: You are most likely using VTL templates in your REST API which transforms the input passed to your Lambda. HTTP APIs do not support VTL.